# sas: do loop in data step for date parameter

Tags: sas

i am doing something stupid like the following. I am new to sas and curious whether the code can be simply using do loop

```
/*STEP 1 - Parameter decloration*/
%let yyyymm0 = 201506;
    /*STEP 1.1 - parm*/
data parm;
    format yyyymm0 $6.;
    yyyymm0 = &yyyymm.;
    format yymm0 $4.;
    yymm0 = substr(yyyymm0, 3, 4);
    format yyyy0 $4.;
    yyyy0 = substr(yyyymm0, 1, 4);
    format mm0 $2.;
    mm0 = substr(yyyymm0, 5, 2);
    format yyyymm1-yyyymm11 $6.;
    format yymm1-yymm11 $6.;
    yyyymm1 = put(intnx('month', input(yyyymm, yymmn6.), -1, 'beginning'), yymmn6.);
    yyyymm2 = put(intnx('month', input(yyyymm, yymmn6.), -2, 'beginning'), yymmn6.);
    yyyymm3 = put(intnx('month', input(yyyymm, yymmn6.), -3, 'beginning'), yymmn6.);
    yyyymm4 = put(intnx('month', input(yyyymm, yymmn6.), -4, 'beginning'), yymmn6.);
    yyyymm5 = put(intnx('month', input(yyyymm, yymmn6.), -5, 'beginning'), yymmn6.);
    yyyymm6 = put(intnx('month', input(yyyymm, yymmn6.), -6, 'beginning'), yymmn6.);
    yyyymm7 = put(intnx('month', input(yyyymm, yymmn6.), -7, 'beginning'), yymmn6.);
    yyyymm8 = put(intnx('month', input(yyyymm, yymmn6.), -8, 'beginning'), yymmn6.);
    yyyymm9 = put(intnx('month', input(yyyymm, yymmn6.), -9, 'beginning'), yymmn6.);
    yyyymm10 = put(intnx('month', input(yyyymm, yymmn6.), -10, 'beginning'), yymmn6.);
    yyyymm11 = put(intnx('month', input(yyyymm, yymmn6.), -11, 'beginning'), yymmn6.);

    yymm1 = substr(yyyymm1,3,4);
    yymm2 = substr(yyyymm2,3,4);
    yymm3 = substr(yyyymm3,3,4);
    yymm4 = substr(yyyymm4,3,4);
    yymm5 = substr(yyyymm5,3,4);
    yymm6 = substr(yyyymm6,3,4);
    yymm7 = substr(yyyymm7,3,4);
    yymm8 = substr(yyyymm8,3,4);
    yymm9 = substr(yyyymm9,3,4);
    yymm10 = substr(yyyymm10,3,4);
    yymm11 = substr(yyyymm11,3,4);

    yyyy1 = substr(yyyymm1,1,4);
    yyyy2 = substr(yyyymm2,1,4);
    yyyy3 = substr(yyyymm3,1,4);
    yyyy4 = substr(yyyymm4,1,4);
    yyyy5 = substr(yyyymm5,1,4);
    yyyy6 = substr(yyyymm6,1,4);
    yyyy7 = substr(yyyymm7,1,4);
    yyyy8 = substr(yyyymm8,1,4);
    yyyy9 = substr(yyyymm9,1,4);
    yyyy10 = substr(yyyymm10,1,4);
    yyyy11 = substr(yyyymm11,1,4);

run;
```

Comment: Why are you attaching formats to your character variables?  Are you under the impression that this will set the length?  Did you mean to use a LENGTH statement instead?

Comment: Why are you creating character variables to hold dates?

Comment: as the task is in monthly regular report. And calculation need to read the last 12 months datasets. For example for 201506, i need to grab the data data_201407 - data_201506. Plus, in the calculation i need those date parameter for assignment of libname and name of the output files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a very useful way of manipulating dates like this in SAS but if you're just doing it to learn SAS then can put them in a do loop with a two dimensional array:

```
%let yyyymm =201506;
data parm;
    format yyyymm1-yyyymm11 yymm1-yymm11 $6.
           yyyy0 $4.;

    array D(3,11) yyyymm1-yyyymm11
                  yymm1-yymm11
                  yyyy1-yyyy11 ;

    yyyymm0 ="&yyyymm";
    yymm0 = substr(yyyymm0, 3, 4);
    yyyy0 = substr(yyyymm0, 1, 4);
    mm0 = substr(yyyymm0, 5, 2);

    *Loop through to process your variables for each month ;
    do i=1 to 11 ;
        D(1,i) = put(intnx('month', input(yyyymm0, yymmn6.), - i, 'beginning'), yymmn6.);
        D(2,i) = substr( D(1,i),3,4);
        D(3,i) = substr( D(2,i) ,1,4);
    end ;
run;
```

Comment: thats exactly i want!

Answer (score 0):

So if the idea is to use these dates to generate dataset (or file) names then why not generate the names in the data step?

```
%let yyyymm =201506;
%let prefix=data_ ;
data parms;
  length start month date 8 dsname $32 ;
  format start date yymmdd10.;
  start = input("&yyyymm.01",yymmdd8.);
  do month=0 to 12 ;
    date = intnx('month',start,month,'b');
    dsname = "&prefix" || substr(put(date,yymmddn8.),1,6);
    output;
  end;
run;
```

proc print; run;

```
Obs         start    month          date      dsname

  1    2015-06-01       0     2015-06-01    data_201506
  2    2015-06-01       1     2015-07-01    data_201507
  3    2015-06-01       2     2015-08-01    data_201508
  4    2015-06-01       3     2015-09-01    data_201509
  5    2015-06-01       4     2015-10-01    data_201510
  6    2015-06-01       5     2015-11-01    data_201511
  7    2015-06-01       6     2015-12-01    data_201512
  8    2015-06-01       7     2016-01-01    data_201601
  9    2015-06-01       8     2016-02-01    data_201602
 10    2015-06-01       9     2016-03-01    data_201603
 11    2015-06-01      10     2016-04-01    data_201604
 12    2015-06-01      11     2016-05-01    data_201605
 13    2015-06-01      12     2016-06-01    data_201606
```

Comment: Hi Tom, as i need to do operation like libname data&yymm0. = "/datawarehouse/&yyyy0./yymm0." How can i achieve that?

Comment: Use the LIBNAME() function.   libref='data'||put(date,yymmn4.);
 path=catx('/','/datawarehouse',year(date),put(date,yymmn4.));
 rc=libname(libref,path);